# Is it possible for me to set a collection of pixels to a (R,G,B) value in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to set a collection of pixels to red by doing this:

```
for(j=0;j<180;j++){
  for(i=0;i<180;i++){
    cv::Vec3b color =frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
    color[0]=0;
    color[1]=0;
    color[2]=255;
    frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = color;
  }
}
```

[Instead it results in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvhXI.png)

I get rgb style layers like what you would see if you looked at a CRT tv really close. How should I be doing it if I would like to set specific pixels to an RGB value? I'm probably doing something really stupid :( If you think I can provide any more information to help please let me know. I'm very new to this :)

Comment: There's little reason to do this with loops, when you have features like this [`assignment operator`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5c947f7e449a4d856a4f3a87fcebd50), [`setTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a0440e2a164c0b0d8462fb1e487be9876) and multiple way to [extract a submatrix](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ad543b6bd296ae1247032c750af4718e1) representing your ROI.

Comment: @DanMašek I assumed there were functions that did it, thanks for pointing them out for me! Curiosity gets the best of me sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input(frame in your case) is not of `CV_8UC3`type.It must be of `CV_8UC4` that is why the pattern of RGB repeats in results image because of non referenced fourth channel which causes one byte shifting for each pixel. You must use `Vec4b` instead of `Vec3b` to get correct result.

Comment: So I assume there would be a channel for Red, Blue ,Green... but what is the 4th channel for?

Comment: Typically an alpha channel (i.e. transparency). If you post how the image is loaded (perhaps your call to imread) that would help track it down.

Comment: @hariprasad is there a page you would recommend I look at regarding return types for stuff like this? It might be in the already existing documentation for 3.2.0 but I have no clue where to find it.

Comment: @Joey The documentation of opencv does not much often from version to version unless new algorithms or optimizations added.For basic data types  you can look at 2.4.13 documentation.http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html